# Proving $(A^B)^C \cong A^{B \times C}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that given sets $A,B,C$, we have $(A^B)^C \cong A^{B \times C}$. Here is my best attempt.

Define the map $\Omega: A^{B \times C} \to (A^B)^C$ sending
$$
\left(f: \underset{(b,c,)}{B \times C} \underset{\mapsto}{\to} \underset{a}{A}\right) \longmapsto \left(\overline{f}: \underset{c}{C} \underset{\mapsto}{\to} \underset{f_c: \underset{b}{B} \underset{\mapsto}{\to} \underset{f(b,c)}{A}}{A^B}\right).
$$
I claim $\Omega$ is a bijection of sets. First suppose that given $f,g \in A \times B$, we have $\Omega(f) = \Omega(g) \in (A^B)^C$. That is, $\overline{f} = \overline{g}$ as maps from $C \to A^B$. So $\overline{f}(c) = \overline{g}(c)$ for all $c$ as maps from $B$ to $A$. In our notation, this means $f_c = g_c$ as maps from $B$ to $A$. So for every $b \in B$, we have $f_c (b) = g_c (b)$, i.e., $f(b,c) = g(b,c)$ for every $b \in B$ and $c \in C$. But that implies $f = g$, so $\Omega$ is injective.

I'm struggling to prove surjectivity and would appreciate some help with that. I'll update this post with another attempt as I continue to work on this more.

Comment: It's probably easiest just to define the inverse map to $\Omega$ directly, using something like $\bar f \mapsto ((b, c) \mapsto \bar f(c)(b))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have got a bit bogged down in the notation. If $f: B \times C \to A$, (i.e. $A^{B \times C}$), you can define $\Omega f: C \to (B \to A)$ (i.e., $(A^B)^C$) by
$$(\Omega f)(c)(b) = f(b, c)$$
Then, for $g : C \to (B \to A)$, you can define $\Phi(g) : B \times C \to A$ by:
$$(\Phi g)(b, c) = g(c)(b)$$

You can now check that $\Omega : A ^ {B \times C} \to (A^B)^C$ and $\Phi: (A^B)^C \to A ^ {B \times C}$ give a bijection between $A^{B \times C}$ and $(A^B)^C$.

Comment: The notation was definitely causing me some trouble, but this makes sense. Thank you!